# How to convert from htaccess to app.yaml for rewrite rule ?

Tags: .htaccess, google-app-engine, app.yaml

Rule:

```
RewriteRule ^register/$    main.php?Type=REGISTER_INDEX&MenuID=102
```

How can I write the above `.htaccess` rewrite rule in GAE `app.yaml` file?